# Биннинг (категоризация) количественной переменной на категории

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

На примере набора данных Титаник, нужно создать столбец `Age_Cathegory` который соответствует столбцу `Age` по маппингу:

`0-10` лет `Child`,

`10-20` лет `Teen`,

`20-max` лет `Adult`,

Нужно использовать функцию `map()`

Comment: В чём ваш вопрос? Вы прочитали документацию по map? Если да, то что именно вам осталось непонятным?

Comment: Вопрос в том, как применить метод map() так, чтобы ключом словаря, поступающего в метод было условие (<6  или >10 & <20), а значением строка, "Child","Adult" и т.д. В Документации приведен пример только со словарем в аргументе `map()`, а функция в аргументе примером не снабжена. Хотелось бы видеть в ответе пример программного кода

Comment: Не надо минусовать вопрос, когда сами не читали ущербную документацию, но привыкли на нее ссылаться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого сущесвует специальная функция [pd.cut()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\download\data\titanic\train.csv')

bins = [0, 10, 20, 150]
labels = ['Child','Teen','Adult']

df['age_cat'] = pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
```

результат:

```
In [124]: df[['Age','age_cat']].sample(frac=1)
Out[124]:
      Age age_cat
788   1.0   Child
67   19.0    Teen
593   NaN     NaN
343  25.0   Adult
446  13.0    Teen
310  24.0   Adult
74   32.0   Adult
..    ...     ...
879  56.0   Adult
817  31.0   Adult
438  64.0   Adult
217  42.0   Adult
693  25.0   Adult
498  25.0   Adult
326  61.0   Adult

[891 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Вот это отличное решение) Спасибо!)

Answer (score 2):

Использование `.map` с функцией в pandas по сути ничем не отличается от использования стандартного питоновского `map` - поэтому для него отдельного примера и не приведено. Авторы документации полагались на то, что если уж человек взялся осваивать библиотеку для питона, то уж основы питона он знает.

Вот вам пример:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['John', 'Tilda', 'Henry'], 'age': [8, 15, 23]})

def categorize_age(age):
    if age < 10:
        return 'Child'
    if age < 20:
        return 'Teen'
    return 'Adult'

df['age_category'] = df.age.map(categorize_age)

print(df)
```

Но на будущее всё-таки рекомендую освоить хотя бы основы питона.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я ожидал какой-то лаконичной записи, о которой я не знал, но, очевидно, придется прописывать функции отдельно.